# Changing remote directory in bat file when FTPing

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I have this current bat file:

```
echo user etm124> ftpcmd.dat
echo testing123>> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd C:\Documents and Settings\etm124\Desktop\>> ftpcmd.dat
echo mput *.txt>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -i -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.DriveHQ.com
del ftpcmd.dat
```

As you can see, I am connecting to a free FTP service, and uploading all .txt files on my desktop. Before uploading, how do I change the remote directory in which I went to upload the files.

With the current script, it just uploads into the root directory. If I wanted to upload to a `Text Files` directory, how would I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the `cd` command.  Currently, your `cd` command is trying to set the directory on the ftp server to `C:\Documents and Settings\etm124\Desktop\.`  1. Pull the current `cd` command that you have out of the `.dat` file. 2. Add a `cd` command to the `.dat` file to set the directory in which you want to upload the file into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `cd` command. Currently, your `cd` command is trying to set the directory on the ftp server to `C:\Documents and Settings\etm124\Desktop\.`

1. Pull the current `cd` command that you have out of the `.dat` file.
2. Add a `cd` command to the `.dat` file to set the directory in which you want to upload the file into.

   ```
   cd C:\Documents and Settings\etm124\Desktop\
   echo user etm124> ftpcmd.dat
   echo testing123>> ftpcmd.dat
   echo cd ftpserver\folder\>> ftpcmd.dat
   echo mput *.txt>> ftpcmd.dat
   echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
   ftp -i -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.DriveHQ.com
   del ftpcmd.dat
   ```

See http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/ftp.html

Answer (score 0):

i know that the question is about changing the remote directory, but if you want to change local directory while running your ftp script (as in the 3rd line of your sample code) use the `lcd` command.

```
echo lcd C:\Documents and Settings\etm124\Desktop\>> ftpcmd.dat
```